# I was not able to see images while converting html page to pdf using javascript

Tags: javascript, html2canvas, html2pdf

here is my code while i download pdf images attributes of html are missing.
suppose in cases like generating invoices we should print tables containing details along with logo.
but images are not displaying in downloaded pdf using this code.Provide me with possible resolution and reason for this.thanks in advance

```js
$(document).on('click', '#btn', function() {
  let pdf = new jsPDF();
  let section = $('body');
  let page = function() {
    pdf.save('pagename.pdf');
  };
  pdf.addHTML(section, page);

})
```

```css
html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#btn {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>HTML with Image</title>
  <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
  <style type="text/css">

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="btn">Convert to PDF</button>
  <div id="text">

    <h2>HTML Page with Image to PDF</h2>
    <img src="http://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/jpeg/PIA17555.jpg" width="300px">

  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
  <script src="custom.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

all the html elements are working fine except images . kindly help me with resolving this.

Answer (score 0):

jsPdf does not support adding images the way you are trying to add them, because addtHtml function uses the html2canvas module, to convert your Html to canvas, so jsPdf can render it into pdf. Please check this link below.

https://weihui-guo.medium.com/save-html-page-and-online-images-as-a-pdf-attachment-with-one-click-from-client-side-21d65656e764